# Use type to access properties instead of concrete instance

Tags: vb.net, linq, reflection, .net-4.7.2

I'm having trouble figuring out how to ask this question (the title is not worded well), so let me start with an example using the `NameOf()` method, because it does something similar to what I'm trying to accomplish.

If I have a class like this:

```vb
Public Class MyClass
    Public Property Foo As Bar
End Class
```

and then I declare an instance of it `Dim instance As New MyClass`, I can then use the `NameOf()` method in one of two ways:

```vb
' Both of these lines will print "Foo"
Console.WriteLine(NameOf(instance.Foo))
Console.WriteLine(NameOf(MyClass.Foo))
```

I would like to implement a method that can accept similar types of parameters, but I cannot figure out how. 
Here is the (extension) method I wrote:

```vb
<Extension()>
Public Function GetPathOfProperty(Of T As Class, TProp)(myObj As T, prop As Expression(Of Func(Of TProp))) As String
    Dim result As String = String.Empty
    Dim foundName As String = String.Empty
    Dim className As String = myObj.GetType().Name
    Dim p As MemberExpression = TryCast(prop.Body, MemberExpression)

    While p IsNot Nothing
        If className = p.Member.DeclaringType.Name Then
            foundName = className + "."
        End If

        result = foundName + p.Member.Name + "." + result
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(foundName) Then
            Exit While
        End If
        p = TryCast(p.Expression, MemberExpression)
    End While

    Return IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(foundName), "", result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1))
End Function
```

Using my above example, I can use it like this:

```vb
' Prints "MyClass.Foo"
Console.WriteLine(instance.GetPathOfProperty(Function() instance.Foo)) 
' Prints "MyClass.Foo.SomeBarProperty"
Console.WriteLine(instance.GetPathOfProperty(Function() instance.Foo.SomeBarProperty))
```

I would like to create another version of this method that is not an extension method, but rather a static method that can be called like (or similar to) this:

```vb
Console.WriteLine(GetPathOfProperty(Function() MyClass.Foo) ' Prints "MyClass.Foo"
```

This way I'd be able to use the function without actually creating an instance of `MyClass` first. And this is where I need help. Since `MyClass` is not a static class, I'm not able to put `MyClass.Foo` in the function call. My first thought was to use Reflection, but I can't figure out how. Is there a parameter type I could use to allow me to do this (and if so, how would that look)? Or is this just a pipe-dream and not possible?

Comment: "T As Class" Class is not a Type; it is a keyword. Maybe T As Type

Comment: You can't reference a type name followed by a property - it isn't valid syntax. So there is no way to do this in VB or C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass in a direct reference to a property on a type, but you can cheat using lambda expressions (Function delegates) by typing the parameter to the delegate (essentially a static [open instance delegate](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/introduction-to-open-instance-delegates/)).

Here is my module to return a path reference from an instance or from a type:

```
Public Module PropertyExt
    <Extension()>
    Public Function TrimStart(Byval src As String, starter As String) As String
        Return If(src.StartsWith(starter), src.Substring(starter.Length), src)
    End Function

    Public Function GetPathOfInstanceProperty(Of TRes)(e As Expression(Of Func(Of TRes))) As String
        Dim b = TryCast(e.Body, MemberExpression)
        Dim ans = ""
        Do
            ans = b.Member.Name.TrimStart("$VB$Local_") & "." & ans
            b = TryCast(b.Expression, MemberExpression)
        Loop While (b IsNot Nothing)
        Return ans.TrimEnd(".")
    End Function

    Public Function GetPathOfTypeProperty(Of T,TRes)(e As Expression(Of Func(Of T,TRes))) As String
        Dim b = TryCast(e.Body, MemberExpression)
        Dim ans = ""
        Do
            ans = b.Member.Name.TrimStart("$VB$Local_") & "." & ans
            Dim tryB = TryCast(b.Expression, MemberExpression)
            If tryB Is Nothing Then
                Dim tryParm = TryCast(b.Expression, ParameterExpression)
                If tryParm IsNot Nothing Then
                    ans = tryParm.Type.Name & "." & ans
                End If
            End If
            b = tryB
        Loop While (b IsNot Nothing)
        Return ans.TrimEnd(".")
    End Function
End Module
```

Which you can use like so:

```
Dim cf = New CInstance()
Dim ipe = PropertyExt.GetPathOfInstanceProperty(Function() cf.Foo.SomeBarProperty)
Dim tpe = PropertyExt.GetPathOfTypeProperty(Function(i As CInstance) i.Foo.SomeBarProperty)
```

NOTE: VB also seems to rename local variables so I added some code to drop the `$VB$Local_` prefix from names - this can be removed if not needed.

PS This seems a lot cleaner/simpler in C# ;)

Comment: This is perfect for what I wanted. Thanks! ... And I definitely agree on the C#, unfortunately, that part is not my call :(